# docker script to be executed not found inside dockerfile run

Tags: dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile in which I first copy the files to the container and then I want to execute them. I check that the files exist and they are executable:

Dockerfile

```less
RUN ls -lisa bin | grep kafka-s

RUN KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(./bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)" \
    && export KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID
```

Output:

```less
Step 5/10 : RUN ls -lisa bin | grep kafka-s
 ---> Running in 1fe07739aadb
31076072      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1376 Jul 14  2023 kafka-server-start.sh
31076073      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1361 Jul 14  2023 kafka-server-stop.sh
31076074      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           860 Jul 14  2023 kafka-storage.sh
31076075      4 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           956 Jul 14  2023 kafka-streams-application-reset.sh
 ---> Removed intermediate container 1fe07739aadb
 ---> 0dc1c3805ed1
Step 6/10 : RUN KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(./bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"     && export KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID
 ---> Running in 61a35afe8423
/bin/sh: ./bin/kafka-storage.sh: not found
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID="$(./bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"     && export KAFKA_CLUSTER_ID' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

So as you can read docker complains `/bin/sh: ./bin/kafka-storage.sh: not found`, why?

What is wrong? The file exists and is executable.